# Spring form input can't be disable

Tags: java, spring, forms, input

I want to disable a `<form:input>` with the attribute disabled, but it's not working.

```
<td class="value">
                <sec:authorize access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_EDIT_DEVICE_INSTALL_DATE')">
                    <form:input path="installDt"  maxlength="10" size="10"  cssClass="installDatePicker" /> 
                    <form:errors path="installDt" cssClass="errormsg" />
                </sec:authorize>
                <sec:authorize access="!hasAnyRole('ROLE_EDIT_DEVICE_INSTALL_DATE')">
                    <form:input path="installDt"  maxlength="10" size="10"  cssClass="installDatePicker" disabled="disabled" /> 
                    <form:errors path="installDt" cssClass="errormsg" />
                </sec:authorize>  
</td>
```

Does anybody have any idea to solve it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I remove the cssClass date picker and set the disabled boolean to true and it works

Answer (score 21):

To disable it, use `disabled=true`. It accepts true|false.

```
<form:input path="installDt"  maxlength="10" size="10"  cssClass="installDatePicker" disabled="true" />
```

Comment: The value at receiving end is null in this case

Answer (score 11):

When I try to do input disable with `disabled="true"` , the data is null at core code, but when I try it with readonly, it did this properly.

Try `readonly="readonly"`

Comment: Yes , when using with `disabled="true"`, redirect to this page can't access values *(eg:validation errors)*. In my case `readonly="true"` at`<form:input>` tag fixed my problem. Thanks for good point.

Answer (score 5):

When I place `disabled="disable"` it won't work

When I place `disabled="true"` the value in the receiving end is null

When I place `readonly="true"` It works for me.